# show the custom message in Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Sorry, I'm not good at English. I have some problem for studying Django.
I wrote the below code to make a form. And I need to show the custom message when user didn't enter the value in text box.

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField( error_messages={'required': 'Please enter title'}, 
                         max_length=128 , 
                         required=True,
                         widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':60}))
    contents  = forms.CharField( required=True,
                         widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 160, 'rows': 20}))
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':60}))
    writed_by = forms.CharField(max_length=100, 
                            required=True,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':60}))
    class Meta:
        model  = Article
        fields = ["title", "writed_by", "email", "contents"]
```

I want to show 'Please enter title' message when didn't enter the title. But form shows the default message.

what is the problem in this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the custom message in the `__init__()` like so:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, 
                            required=True,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 60}))
    class Meta:
        model  = Article
        fields = ["title"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArticleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # add custom error messages
        self.fields['title'].error_messages['required'] = 'Please enter title'
```